# Как правильно разделить assets на namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

Создал второй **layout/admin.html.slim** в котором указал

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "admin", :media => "all"
= javascript_include_tag "admin"
```

Соответственно создал файлы **assets/javascripts/admin.js** и **assets/stylesheets/admin.css** в которых указал:

1) css

```
 *= require_tree ./admin
 *= require style
 *= require_self
```

2) js

```
//= require_tree ./admin
```

И создал директории **assets/javascript/admin** и **assets/stylesheets/admin** в которые помещаю свои файлы.

в **initialize/assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.css admin.js )
```

Проблема в том, что стили все равно изменяют и основной сайт. Т.е. основной layouts/application тоже изменяется.

UPD:
css

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require leftmenu/superfish
 *= require leftmenu/superfish-vertical
 */
```

js

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require leftmenu/hoverIntent
//= require leftmenu/superfish
//= require leftmenu/options
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Можете показать манифесты front-части? assets/javascripts/application.js и assets/stylesheets/application.css ?

Comment: Добавил в тело вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что инструкции

```
*= require_tree .
//= require_tree .
```

Включают в файл все файлы из текущей папке и вложенных подпапок, включая admin. Необходимо переместить все ассеты в подпапку front и заменить эти инструкции на

```
*= require_tree ./front
//= require_tree ./front
```

по аналогии с админ-часть.